# C# and SharePoint 2013 - understanding context and lists

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to get a list of users and the folders they have access to on a SharePoint am already copying files to but can't get my head around the structure of the site so I can get the correct List name in the site.

My URL is `https://mySPsite/sites/MySite`

This is the url that I use to set the context in another function that copies files to the site. The copy locations are in a slightly different format as I use SaveBinaryDirect with the file url in the format `/sites/MySite/Shared Documents/MyFolder/MySubFolder`. The file copy routines work fine.

What I'm trying to do now is get a list of the folders and the users that have access to them. The folders are all of the `MySubFolder` folders in `MyFolder`

The problem that I have is that whatever combination of folder names I try I get an error saying the the list cannot be found in the site. I'm using the solution posted below

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
     ctx.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(i => i.RoleAssignments.Include( ra => ra.Member), i => i.DisplayName ));
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} folder permissions",item.DisplayName);
        foreach (var assignment in item.RoleAssignments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(assignment.Member.Title);
        }
     }
}
```

by Vadim to get the folder permissions. I'm clearly missing the linkage between `WebUri` and `listTitle` and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper code. The key to success is setting proper `query.FolderServerRelativeUrl`.

```
private static void PrintFolderPermission(string webUri, string listTitle)
{
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
    {
        var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        var query = CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery();
        query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/custom-dev/Shared documents/MyFolder/MySubfolder";
        var items = list.GetItems(query);
        ctx.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(i => i.RoleAssignments.Include(ra => ra.Member), i => i.DisplayName));
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.DisplayName + " folder permissions");
            foreach (var assignment in item.RoleAssignments)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(assignment.Member.Title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ironically I didn't have permission to view permissions so couldn't test the code. Thanks for the tip though and I'll mark as correct as it seems to make perfect sense.